# Unable to parse XML in jquery's response from SOAP interface

Tags: jquery, xml, soap

After an AJAX call to a SOAP ui interface, I'm unable to parse the element from the response I get

AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:myURL,
            async:false,
            contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: msgXML,
            success: function(result) {
                debugger;
                console.log('success');
                console.log(result);
                json = result;
                //I would like to parse the object here

            },
            error:function(data){
                console.log(data.responseText);
                debugger;
            }
        });
```

I get the following object in the debugger of google chrome

[image: looking at the result I get from the AJAX success]

I know it's a noob question but I somehow cannot parse what's inside this object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

To parse the data, you have simply to do:

```
result.getElementsByTagName("nameOfTheTagIWantToFind")[0]
```

Cheers!